# Prove or disprove regarding sequences

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, examples-counterexamples

Question:

> Find a sequence $\displaystyle \{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $a_n\rightarrow 0$ and $n\left|a_{n+1}-a_n\right|\rightarrow \infty$. If no such sequence exists, prove it.

My try:

At first I tried to find such sequence, but it seems to me that such sequence exists.

Next, I used the fact that if $a_n$ converges to some finite limit, then $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n=0$, but it gets me to a dead end and I don't understand how I should tackle it.

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Is the $n|a_{n+1}-a_n|$ intentional? Regarding the $n$ factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}.$$

Then
$$
\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n\rvert=\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|=
\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\ge\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
$$
and hence
$$
n\lvert a_{n+1}-a_n\rvert\ge\sqrt{n}\to\infty.
$$

Comment: No it is not. The $(-1)^{n+1}$ and $-(-1)^n$ have the same sign.

Comment: you are right.${}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, great example and explanation. (+1)